# How to set select option according to my vaildation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, select

I have jsp code like this
I need to validate according to label value & need set option as validation, options are fill by Database

```
<c:forEach var="roomOccupanice" items="${RoomOccRequestNow}">   
    <label value ="${roomOccupanice}"  class="roomOccupanice" id="roomOccupanice">${roomOccupanice}</label>
            <div class="custom-select-container">
               <select id="roomType" name="roomType" class="roomType">
                    <option value="N/A" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                    <c:forEach var="roomType" items="${RoomTypeRequestNow}">
                        <option value="${roomType}">${roomType}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>   
                <label class="select-arrow"></label>
            </div>
            <!-- End -->
            <div class="custom-select-container">
               <select id="roomCount" name="roomCount" class="roomCount">
                    <option value="N/A" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                    <c:forEach var="roomCount" items="${RoomCountRequestNow}">
                        <option value="${roomCount}">${roomCount}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>   
                <label class="select-arrow"></label>
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

my .js Code
here my validation  part in a js

```
 $(".roomOccupanice").each(function(){  
  var label = $(this).text(); // It will get current label text
    $(".roomType").each(function(){
      if (label == "Double"){  //  i just hard cord "Double" now but it get from request
         $(this).value = "Deluxe";  // need to set a value in select option  it's already in one of options 
       } 
    });
});
```

[image: Need to set that red cycle select option as "Deluxe"]

Need to set that red cycle select option as "Deluxe"

Comment: This won't resolve your pb but ids must be unique .. just saying `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the options set to match the ones that belong to the current label `$('.roomtype', <ASSOCIATED SELECT ELEMENT>))`..

```
$(".roomOccupanice").each(function(){
    var $t = $(this),
    $select = $t.next().find('select');
    if ($t.text().toLowerCase() == "double"){
        $select[0].selectedIndex = $select.find('option').index($select.find('option[value^=Deluxe]')[0]);
    }

});
```

Comment: it's not work , i go through debug point it's not going to inside this function  $(".roomType", $select[0]).each(function(){ it's comes out every time

Comment: I apology, I did not get your HTML sturcture ... check last edit ... Also here is the [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f00bar/3uw3G/) `;)`

Comment: If this solved your pb then you could check this answer as your solution `;)` If you have any question about this code then just ask .. this said jQuery documentation is really good !

Answer (score 1):

Check [val function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of jQuery:

```
$("#roomType").val("yourOptionName");
```

So for your example:

```
$(".roomOccupanice").each(function () {
var label = $(this).text();
  $(this).next(".custom-select-container").children("select").each(function() {
      if (label == "Double") {
        $(this).val("double");
      }
   });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bnT6/4/).

Comment: yea i tried that when i do that only first label's(single) select option change as "Deluxe" but i need a current 1 (double)

Comment: Ah there is one logic error here, since you do not specify what roomType you need, it changes values of all of them when label == "Double". I'll try to correct it.

Comment: Roomtype is Deluxe, it's already in one of options, i need to set that according to occupancy label single or double or triple, in my js i hardcore that if (label == "Double"){} for test to set value in select option,

Comment: I have improved the solution. Please check if it works for you now. Updated fiddle as well. I think it does what you intended it to.

Comment: The loop over the select seams useless to me `:/` I would put the test `if(label == "double")` right after `var label..` then doiing `$(this).next().children('select').val('double')`  inside if condition curly braces `:p`

Comment: Yes, that could work too, just wanted to stick to what Yasa had in the first place, perhaps he has more logic there that required looping over options.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to select a list item through its index

```
document.getElementById("roomCount").selectedIndex = <yournumber>;
```